# How do I disable the migrations feature in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, database-design, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

**Background**

We engineer database models and application models separately (RDMBS architects vs OOP engineers).  From what I've seen regarding Rails versus domain/key normal form, Rails migrations cannot easily duplicate all the features of a well-designed enterprise RDBMS (if at all) so we don't migrate and instead use other tools to build databases (nevermind the problem of object-relational impedance mismatch).  Data integrity and DB performance are too valuable to us to risk RDBMS model changes by any developer.

**Question**

For whatever reason, we now have a Rails app that has made damaging DB changes through migrations.  How do I cleanly disable this feature in an existing Rails application?

I have my theories but I want to know what the world thinks.

Comment: Always best to share your theories and show what you've tried in a question.

Comment: If you use capistrano for deployment, I bet you could just configure it to skip the `db:migrate` rake task. Not sure about other deployment tools.

Comment: You could look into something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112074/overriding-rails-default-rake-tasks) and just overwrite all the database rake tasks to do nothing - or display a message "Naughty developer" maybe?  I don't think there is actually anyway to disable them via a configuration option

Comment: Agreed, just write your own tasks, or create a migration template that allows either nothing, or a subset of stuff you deem "ok"; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5202008/438992.

Comment: @Brian. Yes, using Capistrano but was hoping for something even lower level than cap or rake. I believe we can modify one of the dev databases even without a cap deployment and I would like to avoid that as well. I was thinking more along the lines of replacing `require 'rails/all'` with an itemized list. Removing migrate from the cap task would be a good second layer of enforcement. Another option is to create two DB users: one for DB work, and one for Rails with less rights. Not sure how that will go over but probably the smartest route. Would still like to hobble Rails though.

Comment: You probably could work that out, I'd expect that list to get long though :-). This is essentially what the rails-api project does to slim down the dependencies: https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/master/lib/rails-api/application.rb

Comment: Or maybe something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527459/using-datamapper-with-existing-rails-application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This came up again when testing finally came to the front.  Thus, I took deeper look and came up with the following thanks, in part, to the comments left on the question.  This removes all rake DB capabilities and tests still run fine.  (In case anyone is wondering, we clone the test DB from elsewhere when we need to refresh it.)

Add this to the `Rakefile`:

```
# Disable DB migrations, DB test preparing, etc.
Rake::Task.tasks.each do |t|
    if t.name[0,3] == "db:"
        t.clear
        t.add_description("!!! Disabled in favor of enterprise design at Acme.")
    end
end
```

Comment out all the fixtures in `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
#fixtures :all
```

Comment: This seems no longer to work with Rails 7 as during test it will call `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintail_test_schema`
I added `config.active_record.maintain_test_schema = false` to the test environment

Answer (score 5):

In juanitogan's answer, we disable all db tasks. In my case I still wanted to be able to run `db:schema:load`. Here the slightly modified code for the `Rakefile`:

```
# Disable migrations
Rake::Task.tasks.each do |t|
  if t.name.start_with?("db:migrate")
    t.clear
    t.add_description("Disabled; Load the data model via db:schema:load.")
    t.actions << proc { puts "Migrations ignored. That's ok. Please see README."}
  end
end
```

When creating models, you can append the `--no-migration` option like so: `rails g model abc --no-migration`

Comment: Do you mean to allow `db:schema:load` ? This will apply schema.rb to the current DB env and destroy all data. I think you mean to allow `db:schema:dump`, which creates a schema.rb that matches the database. You would still want to prevent `db:schema:load` though, not just migrate tasks.

Comment: actually, I meant `db:schema:load`, because I have a prescribed schema and want to load it.